# Why this remote request won't detect params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Even if I put it checked and submit, transaction won't be fired:(
Why is that?? `body` and everything else is being submit fine.
It just doesn't detect and run transaction even if I check it and submit...
Anyone has any idea?

**controller**

```
if params[:comment][:call]
    transaction.....
end
```

**view Form** (remote with ajax)

```
<%=form_for(([@community, @comment]), :remote => true, :class => 'form' ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box :call, :label => 'call' %> call
        <div class="form-actions">
            <div class="input-append">
                <%= f.text_field :body, :id => "input", :class => "box" %>  
            <button type="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**Comment model**

```
attr_accessible :icon, :call
....
def call
    @call ||= "0"
end

def call=(value)
    @call = value
end
```

Comment: In the log output in your shell, the third line of the request shows the params hash. Do you find `{"comment"=>{"call"=>...}}` there?

Comment: @ChristophPetschnig "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HPhF4ICEtwPML44rnLfGGyBCFypycmR76eC7vL8PNPE=", "comment"=>{"call"=>"1", "body"=>"testbody"}, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"comments", "community_id"=>"134"

Comment: This looks fine. That's why I'm really confused:(

Comment: I recommend to pry into the controller action (`require 'pry'; binding.pry`) and see what happens there. You need to add `gem 'pry'` to your `Gemfile` as well and run `bundle install`.

Comment: @ChristophPetschnig Thanks for reply:) Can't it be more simple? Is it way hard to figure out from the code I wrote?